# how to compare multiple attribute pairs using Xpath 1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath

The goal is to select only those nodes that

1. have a sibling node with a child node with an attribute value that matches an attribute value of node that needs to be selected.
2. have a sibling node with a with an attribute value that matches another attribute value of node that needs to be selected.

I can see why an Xpath expression like the following will not select the node set I'm looking for:

```
//first/second[@attr1=parent::first/second/third/@attrx][@attr2=parent::first/second[@attry]
```

Is it possible to select the node set I'm looking for and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Would these work for you?

nodes that have a sibling node with a child node with an attribute
value that matches an attribute value of node that needs to be selected:

```
//*[(@attribute = ./following-sibling::*/*/@attribute)
    or 
    (@attribute = ./preceding-sibling::*/*/@attribute)]
                    --- sibling node --- ------------                 
                                               |
                                   child node with a same attribute
```

nodes have a sibling node with a with an attribute value that matches
another attribute value of node that needs to be selected.

```
//*[(@attribute1 = ./following-sibling::*/@attribute2)
    or 
    (@attribute1 = ./preceding-sibling::*/@attribute2)]
                     --- sibling node with another attribute
```